# Can't use reactivestream Subscriber with akka stream sources

Tags: akka-stream, reactive-streams

I'm trying to attach a reactivestream subscriber to an akka source.

My source seems to work fine with a simple sink (like a foreach) - but if I put in a real sink, made from a subscriber, I don't get anything.

My context is:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}
import org.reactivestreams.{Subscriber, Subscription}

implicit val system =  ActorSystem.create("test")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system)

class PrintSubscriber extends Subscriber[String] {
  override def onError(t: Throwable): Unit = {}
  override def onSubscribe(s: Subscription): Unit = {}
  override def onComplete(): Unit = {}
  override def onNext(t: String): Unit = {
    println(t)
  }
}
```

and my test case is:

```
val subscriber = new PrintSubscriber()
val sink = Sink.fromSubscriber(subscriber)

val source2 = Source.fromIterator(() => Iterator("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"))
val source1 = Source.fromIterator(() => Iterator("xxx", "yyy", "zzz"))
source1.to(sink).run()(materializer)
source2.runForeach(println)
```

I get output:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Why don't I get xxx, yyy, and zzz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing the Reactive Streams specs for the `Subscriber` below:

> Will receive call to onSubscribe(Subscription) once after passing an
>   instance of Subscriber to Publisher.subscribe(Subscriber). No further
>   notifications will be received until Subscription.request(long) is
>   called.

The smallest change you can make to see some items flowing through to your subscriber is

```
override def onSubscribe(s: Subscription): Unit = {
  s.request(3)
}
```

However, keep in mind this won't make it fully compliant to the Reactive Streams [specs](http://www.reactive-streams.org/). It being not-so-easy to implement is the main reason behind higher level toolkits like Akka-Streams itself.